# Outlook Calendar link to create a new event URL is no longer working?

Tags: php, html, web, outlook-2010

In our web application we providing the below link to create a calendar event when I click on the button it will open the outlook mail portal and add an event link

https://outlook.live.com/owa/?path=/calendar/view/month&rru=addevent

&startdt=20200419T133000Z

&enddt=20200419T134000Z

&subject=Dear Andy, Calender description here&location=Mumbai

But unfortunately, the above link is no longer working, could anybody help us to fix the issue and tell what is the exact link format that will create a calendar event.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working now. At least the add event pop-up does appear. Still the time is parsed in a wrong way. At the moment you should be using following format: `2020-04-19T13:30:00Z`

Still texts are also parsed incorrectly and show plus signs. Pointing to `outlook.live.com/calendar/0/deeplink/compose` instead of `outlook.live.com/owa/` is fixing this but will break the timezone :)

Never found any docs on this.